# Why standard output is not printed on command line?

Tags: command-line, printing, c++

I'm new in programming. I run simple C++ program, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
std::cout<<"What?";}
```

by using the terminal by typing `g++ Program.cpp`.

No error is returned after compiling, but the standard output is not shown on the line, which I think it sohould return `What?` as typed after `std::cout<<`.

What can be the cause why the standard output is not shown in terminal?

Comment: Generic coding questions should be asked on http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `g++` command compiles the program. You also have to link and build the program.

Try `gcc -o program Program.cpp`

After that you'll have to run it:

```
./program
```

Also, you forgot `using namespace std;`

Comment: It's a bad practice to use `using namespace std;` 
If you have, for example, a method that is named like a method in the std library, you can have unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it should be something like this:

```
sneetsher@mx5:~/Desktop$ g++ Program.cpp 
sneetsher@mx5:~/Desktop$ ./a.out 
What?sneetsher@mx5:~/Desktop$
```

Notice where `What?` is hiding, because you didn't include any new line `\n` or `<<endl;`!!!